# Lift answer ban with only 1 answer?

Tags: discussion, ban

My problem was I created an account 2 days ago and I posted an answer instead of a comment because of lack of reputation. After that I found that I was banned from answering posts. From the help centre I get it that the way to lift this ban was fixing my existing posts.

So, my question was I have only 1 answer posted right now, so is the only way I can lift the ban by getting up votes on my one answer? Is there no other way?

2nd, is it enough to get 1 up vote for that only 1 answer? (How many are needed actually?)

3rd, what if I cannot get up votes on my only answer? Will my account be banned forever? Should I create another account?

Comment: Only one? Do you have any deleted answers?

Comment: @bjb568 No, I did not delete any answer before , for this account total I have answer 2 question and 1 of it is reported and deleted by vote, and I get ban after that, so now I have only 1 answer valid remaining

Comment: Huh… never heard of that.

Comment: ya, I was just new here. and in the trouble

Comment: Are there other users on the same IP address that have ban's?

Comment: @ToonKrijthe im not sure about that, but stackoverflow ban is base on ip address not account ?

Comment: As far as I know, it starts on account, but sometimes users create other accounts to avoid the ban and then an IP ban follows. Possibly hurting other users of the same IP.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe so any solution on this ?

Comment: If so, wait until a mod sees it and they can probably help you. I will post a flag in order to get the mods attention. You can also flag this. But be sure you tell the truth, mods can see all of your activity deleted or not.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe but that was stack overflow, it is fine too ?

Comment: You can do it on stack overflow too. But the point is to get their attention. Besides, this post has all your information.

Answer (score 18):

You had multiple answers that were downvoted and deleted, as well as multiple questions that were downvoted, closed and deleted.

A larger problem, however, is that this is clearly an account you created to work around the suspension of your main account on Stack Overflow. I have deleted your account as a result, along with the other account you just created to work around these bans. If you continue to do this, you will be blocked entirely from using the site.

I highly recommend waiting out the suspension of your main account and cleaning up your questions and answers there when you can return.